# how do i initialize(initState) parameters sent from another page in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

help me pls. I send parameters from page A with this code

```
              onTap: () =>
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'edit', arguments: {
                "id_pet": pid,
                "category_pet": pnombre,
              }),
```

And i received them so, i try with this code but it doesnt work for me :

```
var selectedDropDownValueCat;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    /* ---- look this is,here i want initialize the value received from othe page ------- */

    //selectedDropDownValue = "New";
    selectedDropDownValue = (arguments["category1_pet"]); // it doesnt work :(
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    dynamic arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Edit"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual),
            onPressed: _FotoA,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            onPressed: _FotoB,
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: MenuWidget(),
      body: Form(key: formKey, child: _publicarForm(context, arguments)),
    );
  }
```

but i want initialize this values in the initState in order to have the value of the other page

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in initState

```
Future.delayed(Duration,zero, () {
            dynamic arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
            selectedDropDownValue = (arguments["category_pet"]);
});
```